# How to add Peers in Quorum Single Member Blockchain Network in Azure?

Tags: peers, quorum, microsoft-azure, enode, cakeshop

I'm using the QSMBN(Quorum Single Member Blockchain Network) provided by Azure, and I'm trying to connect one external node to the quorum network, but when I try to add peer displays this message "Request to add peer is sent", but nothing happens,
Anyone have any idea of what do I have to do?